# source(): Error: Replacement has length zero

Tags: r

I couldn't figure out where the problem might lay or how to offer you some sample data: 
I have a fairly long script, so I separate it in parts. The second part is about merging columns.
I measured the increment from beech by directly measuring the increment they had in the last 3 years. For spruces it was easier, I could just measure the height of this years tip and then the height of the whorls. Like this year’s height – the height of the next whorls is this years increment. To form a common column with the increment I (and later rename it) I made a loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$Species[i]=="Fi"){
    print(i)
    df$`Length Beech 2019 [cm]`[i] <- df$`Height [cm] 2019`[i] - df$`Höhe Spruce 2018 [cm]`[i]
  } 
}
```

This part runs flawless in the same script. But if I copy the whole part of rearranging my dataframe to another R script,

```
> source("2 RedesignDF.R")
[1] 2
Error in df$`Length Beech 2019 [cm]`[i] <- df$`Height [cm] 2019`[i] -  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

I get this mistake. The first 10 values are:

```
> str(df$`Length Beech 2019 [cm]`)
 num [1:113] 25 NA NA 25 23 NA 14.5 19.5 NA NA ...
> str(df$`Height [cm] 2019`)
 num [1:113] 302 186 188 306 258 ...
> str(df$`Höhe Spruce 2018 [cm]`)
 num [1:113] NA 176 178 NA NA ...
```

My first tree is a beech, therefore the first spruce height is empty. I assume this is the source for my mistake, but my confusion stems from the fact that this was not a problem when running it in the same script.

I made some sample data:

```
Species <- c("Bu", "Fi", "Fi", "Bu", "Bu", "Fi", "Bu", "Bu", "Fi", "Fi")
`Length Beech 2019 [cm]` <- c(15.5, NA, NA, 23, 20, NA, 14, 18.5, NA,  NA)
`Height [cm] 2019` <- c(298, 179.5, 306.5, 306.5, 258.5, 188.5, 186, 301.5, 244, 192)
`Höhe Spruce 2018 [cm]` <- c(NA, 169.5, 271, NA,  NA, 170,  NA, NA, 233.5, 188)

df <- data.frame(Species, `Length Beech 2019 [cm]`, `Height [cm] 2019`, `Höhe Spruce 2018 [cm]`)
```

If someone could explain me, why this happens I would be very glad.

Thank you ahead!

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into RStudio and ran it on your sample data. I didn't get any errors, including when sourcing it from another script. Perhaps the error is somewhere after the first 10 rows? You could restart your R session and try again.

Comment: This also runs fine for me, though I need to specify `check.names=FALSE` when constructing the data.frame. I can recreate the error by removing a column, check the spellings of the columns is correct.

Comment: @meenaparam Code in question is working but not producing the output. You can see `Length Beech 2019`   column has NAs not the difference where `Species == Fi`.

Comment: @Qiyuan I hadn't understood your problem before but I think the answer posted below by someone else gives you what you are after.

Comment: Thank you all, at my computer it already crashes at the first spruce (therefore the `print()`). I will try it on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

I executed your code and found out that it is not even producing output in the same script. You can see after executing the code you given the output is same as input.

I have rectified your code and it is producing the output. you can try it also for another r script.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$Species[i]=="Fi"){
    print(i)
    df$Length.Beech.2019..cm.[i] <- 
              df$Height..cm..2019[i] - df$Höhe.Spruce.2018..cm.[i]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Source can't work with ä, ö, ü and ß. So either all these must be removed or the encoding must be specified.

```
source("2 RedesignDF.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Anyway, thank you all for your help!